# If constexpr compile time crash for wrong branch

Tags: c++, constexpr, static-assert

I have a serialization function that does something like:

```
class Serializer
{
    template<typename T>
    T read(const std::string& source)
    {
        if constexpr(std::is_same<T, int>::value)
        {
            return std::stoi(source);
        }
        else if constexpr(std::is_same<T, float>::value)
        {
            return std::stof(source);
        }
        else
        {
            assert(false);
            return T();
        }
    }
};
```

What I would like to do is replace the run-time assert with a compile-time assert (like static_assert), to detect that an implementation is missing at compile-time. Full function specialization would be an option to detect a missing implementation, but that is not really an option for me because it is a member function which might require a bunch of members from the encapsulating class. Is there any way to do something like a static assert that does not get triggered if the constexpr branch is not hit?

Comment: There are better ways (IMO) to make the function even more generic, and that will let it handle many more types, and even user-defined types: String streams and `operator>>`. It even will lead to build errors when a type is missing overloads of `operator>>`, just like you want.

Comment: That makes sense if you deserialize to an existing value, I'm trying to deserialize objects constructing them from factories that the serializers reference, which you don't have access to in the stream operator.

Comment: Agreed, use type traits instead (i.e. create `SerializerTraits` and use it).

Comment: The body of the function you show could be replaced by `T value; std::istringstream iss(source); iss >> value; return value;`. Factories doesn't play any part of that.

Comment: Not all types T are default constructible, and other types of T need to be constructed from resource managers. These answers are really unrelated to the static assert question though....

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If. The last 2 bubbles about type-dependent expressions are what you want

Comment: Thank you that is what i was looking for! Place it as an answer and ill accept it.

Comment: Traits are a good solution. You could implement traits for the standard types, and then for custom type the generic catch-all trait could call a static `T::deserialize` (or similar) function. But I still recommend using `std::istream` to read instead of strings, as then it doesn't matter where the input is coming from (a string, a file, there are even wrappers for network sockets).

Comment: Although to be honest, what is the reason you implement your own serialization? There are many good libraries that already exists and are well-tested. If this is just for some training or exercise then sure go ahead, but don't reinvent the wheel for nothing.

Comment: I just mentioned the resource managers and factories and the fact that some types are not default constructible, how does this not matter? Anyway @Lawrence already gave an answer with the dependent_false explained in the cppreference.

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe: If you want to post an answer to your own question, youy should post it *as an answer*, not in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `static_assert(false);` does not depend on the template parameters, the compiler can check this assertion before the point of instantiation in the two phase lookup.
Thus, for instance, the following `static_assert` correctly works for your purpose:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mjVYp409liPPya4F)

```
class Serializer
{
public:    
    template<typename T>
    T read(const std::string& source)
    {        
        if constexpr(std::is_same<T, int>::value)
        {
            return std::stoi(source);
        }
        else if constexpr(std::is_same<T, float>::value)
        {
            return std::stof(source);
        }
        else
        {
            static_assert(!std::is_same<T, T>::value);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`static_assert( std::is_same<T, int>::value || std::is_same<T, float>::value );` solves the demonstrated problem.

In general, no, the `else` branch cannot have a `static_assert(false)` in it.  You can do hacks to permit something similar, but they are of questionable legality.

Possibly the easiest solution would be to just not return from `else`, and have your compiler warn when you have a function that does not return a value.

You might want to `static_assert(!std::is_same<T,void>{})` just to catch that corner case.  ;)